# JavaScript GET Request throws 404 error

Tags: javascript, express, get, requirejs, http-status-code-404

I have this code.This is one file.

```
function success2(data) { 
  alert(data);
}
function addButton(){
   alert("adding " + $("#topic").val());
  $.post("/add",{topic:$("#topic").val()},success2);
  return false;
}
function getButton(){
   alert("Geting " + $("#topic").val());
  $.get("/gettopic",{topic:$("#topic").val()},success2);
  return false;
}


$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#addButton").click(addButton);
  $("#getButton").click(getButton);     
});
```

This is in a separate file.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/",function(request,response){
    response.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/views/index.html");
});

var data = [];
router.post('/add', function(req,res){
    data.push(req.body.topic);
    res.json(req.body.topic);
});

router.get('/gettopic', function(req,res){
    let result = req.query.topic
    res.json(result;
});

function getTopic(name){
    for(let i = 0;i<data.length){
        if(name == data[i])
            return data[i];
    }
    return null;
}   

module.exports = router;
```

And here is the main file.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');   //new
var routes = require("./routes");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  //new
app.use(bodyParser.json());                          //new

app.use('/', express.static('./'));
app.use('/js', express.static('./public/js'));
app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000);
```

When I send the "gettopic" GET request it throws a 404 error "GET http://localhost:3000/gettopic?topic=sdfsd 404 (Not Found)". I was also experiencing this error with POST requests but after re-writng the code many times, some of the request now work and I have no idea what I did differently.

Comment: Please post a reproducible code in order to experience that. Also, please think about posting the main file that require your module to execute the file that contains the routes.

Comment: hint: you're requesting `gettopic` with a query parameter

Comment: Forgot `app.use(router);`?

Comment: @AnthonyB I added the file but I am not sure what you mean by reproducible code. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. By _reproducible_ I mean an example that we can use on our own server to reproduce the error and fix it.

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not sure why that is a problem. It is my understanding that query is used for POST request and body is used for GET request. What am I not understanding? And Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user9135258 - I've never used express, so, I may not understand what you're saying - all I did, however, was [read the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) regarding route parameters - to me, it looks like your get is like a simpler version of the example in the link